# Where to find model parameters of a simple Weyl semimetal?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-insulators, density-functional-theory, weyl-semimetal

A famous continuum model of Dirac semimetal is essentially two copies of the following Hamiltonian (up to some chirality reversal)
$$h=\begin{pmatrix}
M(k) & Ak_+ \\
Ak_- & -M(k)
\end{pmatrix}$$
with $k_\pm=k_x\pm ik_y$ and $M(k)=M_0-M_1k_z^2-M_2(k_x^2+k_y^2)$. For instance, this is found on page 8 of this seminal [work](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.5636.pdf). There, the fitting parameter values of $A,M_{0,1,2}$ are given for a realistic Dirac semimetal and widely used as a reference.

Actually, $h$ is also a Weyl semimetal model on its own. So are there any similar parameter values given for some typical Weyl materials?